# Add dropshadow in coregraphics - goes outside of context bounds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to add a dropshadow to a button i've drawn in coregraphics. Other than making the button smaller than the frame, (which is messy coding as in future you'll forget about that and wonder why your button isn't the size it should be), what options do i have to draw the shadow? It's a custom shape, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add it to you CALayer:

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// iOS 4.0 or later
[self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
[self.layer setShadowRadius:1.f];
```

If that won't work for you, let me know and I will post some code CG code.

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer to the question at hand - the question was about clipping of the shadow, not creating one. Layer shadow will still be clipped by the parent view (assuming the shadowed layer has a superview the size of the button).

Comment: Just for the record: Once I wrote exactly the same code to get the dropShadow effect of text on a UITextField that was on a semitransparent UIToolbar that was partially overlapping a UITextView. Visually the drop shadows was fine but scroll/drag speed in the UITextView was notably slowed down due to this. Approx. 50-60fps went to 30-40fps, just because of the shadow. Better do this with CoreGraphics :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I got the question correctly, you're looking for a way to stop clipping of the shadow. This is easy to achieve, assuming you have a view hierarchy in which the shadowed view resides, just turn off `clipsToBounds` on the superview of the shadowed view (and if needed on the superview's superview).

Be careful though, as there may've been other things your views were clipping and you didn't want to be seen (although normally this shouldn't be a problem).